# Set fengyuanchen jQuery Cropper.js v3.0.0 Preview Size to Same as Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, preview, cropperjs

I'm having a slight issue with fengyuanchen jQuery Cropper.js v3.0.0.  I'm trying to override the default preview code to make it the same size as the original image's display size.

The problem that I'm currently having is that once the image's height exceeds that of the original image's display size, the preview becomes quite a bit larger than the original.  I'd prefer it to remain at the same height.

Here is the behavior that I'm describing.  Note the preview's height:
[image: Large preview]

The default behavior displays a preview that is smaller than the original image:

[image: Default image preview]

What's I'd like is to make the preview remain at the same height as the original image, and NOT exceed it:

[image: Preview at same height as original image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col col-6">
  <img id="image" src=picture.jpg>
</div>
<div class="col col-3">
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>

//css
.preview {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px;
}

//JS:
$(function() {
  var $preview = $('.preview');
  var  cropper = $('#image').cropper({
      ready: function (e) { 
         var $clone = $(this).clone().removeClass('cropper-hidden'); 

         $clone.css({ 
           display: 'block', 
           width: '100%', 
           minWidth: 0, 
           minHeight: 0, 
           maxWidth: 'none', 
           maxHeight: 'none' 
         }); 

         $preview.css({ 
           width: '100%', 
           overflow: 'hidden'//,
           //maxHeight: $(this).cropper('getContainerData').height + 'px'
         }).html($clone); 
      },
      crop: function(e) {
        var imageData          = $(this).cropper('getImageData'), 
            previewAspectRatio = e.width / e.height, 
            previewWidth       = $preview.width(),
            previewHeight      = previewWidth / previewAspectRatio,
            imageScaledRatio   = e.width / previewWidth; 

    //if (previewHeight > $(this).cropper('getContainerData').height) {
         //??? 
    //}
        $preview.height(previewHeight).find('img').css({ 
              width: imageData.naturalWidth / imageScaledRatio, 
              height: imageData.naturalHeight / imageScaledRatio, 
              marginLeft: -e.x / imageScaledRatio, 
              marginTop: -e.y / imageScaledRatio
        }); 
      } 
    });
});
```

Comment: OK, I think I've figured it out.  I'll be answering my own question on Monday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I didn't need all that much code to size the preview the way I wanted to.  I just needed to set the preview's maximum dimensions to that of the original BEFORE instantiating the cropper.

For some reason, I needed to add 4 pixels to the height to make the preview exactly the same height as the original image.  Perhaps the cropper canvas adds extra height and width around the image?

```
$(function() {
  var $image = $('#image'),
      $image.height() + 4;

  $('.preview').css({ 
     width: '100%', //width,  sets the starting size to the same as orig image  
     overflow: 'hidden',
     height:    height,
     maxWidth:  $image.width(),
     maxHeight: height
   });

  $image.cropper({
      preview: '.preview'
  });
});
```